# import error even after installing the utils in python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

I am trying to run an image recognition code. Even after installing 'utils' I am still getting error that module not found. What should I change?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/  Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can NOT copy and paste your image into our IDEs to fix your code.

Comment: What makes you think the thing you installed is the `utils` module you're looking for?

Comment: You installed some random guy's completely unrelated `python3_utils` module. It looks like you're trying to execute a line out of some Tensorflow internal file; taking a wild guess at what drove you to do that, you may have installed the Python 2 version of Tensorflow on Python 3, or skipped protocol buffer installation, leading to problems loading Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your python version is compatible. According to docs it's up to python 3.4 and you seem to be using 3.6. Source - https://pypi.org/project/python3-utils/#data